# Qt5: How to solve this trouble. Custom QWidget with custom paintEvent() vs. QWidget move() function

Tags: c++, qt, position, qwidget, paintevent

first post here, I also need it to help others.

I'm just new at QT/c++, but with years of hobby making programming things, I'm progressing relatively fast.

I'm trying to learn it by making a game, so on, I made, besides other things, a custom sprite class that inherits from QWidget.
I reimplemented, as a common practice, the paintEvent function, using some tricks, qpixmap/qpainter, json files, spritesheets, codehelpers made by my self, to succefully play an animation with stances like idle/walking/attacking.

All went perfect until I tried to move it while walking by the function move(int x, int y) from QWidget.

The problem, I think, is that every time I call "move" function it updates/refresh/repaint the QWidget by calling paintEvent function again, chopping my animation, generating several issues, etc. etc.

I can't to figure out how to move it without repainting or waiting the animation to finish, or what I'm missing. It seems there are no other ways to move a QWidget.
I belive the problem is in another event function that's being called by a emitted signal, probably moveEvent, but I reimplemented it keeping it empty and the result was the same.

Do you have any idea? Should I remake it all in another way to skip this trouble? Or is it as simple as I can't see the coin opposite to me?

Ask for code if needed.
Thank you so much, Luna.

---

EDIT 1:

```
customsprite::customsprite(QWidget *parent, QString spriteName) : QWidget(parent)
{
// qpm is a QPixmap
qpm_idle.load(":/Assets/sprites/" + spriteName + ".png");
qpm_walk.load(":/Assets/sprites/" + spriteName + "_walk.png");
... 
// here goes a custom class to load json files for each sprite sheet
// the json contains x,y,h,w info to draw the animation
...
//some int,bools,qstrings
...
// fps is QTimer
fps.setInterval(33);
connect(&fps,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(update()));
fps.start();
}


//the paintEvent:
void customsprite::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *){
//
QPainter qp(this);
QRect targetR(xMove,0,spriteW,spriteH);
QRect sourceR(jhV[status].getFrameX(jhV[status].namesV[spriteFg]),0,spriteW*sizeDivisor,spriteH*sizeDivisor);
// things abouts consulting jsonhelper info
switch (status){ // status is to know if should draw idle or walk animation
case 0:
    qp.drawPixmap(targetR,qpm_idle,sourceR);
    break;
case 1:
    xMove = xMove + 1;
    targetR = QRect(xMove,0,spriteW,spriteH);
    qp.drawPixmap(targetR,qpm_walk,sourceR);
    break;
default:
    break;
}


// all this works fine
if(!reversingAnimation && shouldAnimate){ // simple bool options
    spriteFg++; // an int counter refering to which frame should be drawed
    if(spriteFg == jhV[status].getSSSize()){ // this consults the json files by a custom jsonhelper, it works fine
        if(reversible){
            reversingAnimation = true;
            spriteFg = jhV[status].getSSSize() - 1;
        }else if(!reversible){
            spriteFg = 0;
            emitSignals();

            if(animateOnce == true){
                shouldAnimate = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
//here goes a similar the above code to to handle the animation playing in reverse, nothing important
}
```

Then in my generic QMainWindow I add an instance of my customsprite class, set its parent as QMainWindow, it appears, play the animation.
The problem is when I try to use:

```
//cs is customsprite
cs->move(cs->x()+1,cs->Y());
```

It moves, but interrumping the animation several times.
I have tried also putting it with a "isWalking" bool filter inside the paintEvent, but it's the same.

EDIT 2:
The "xMove" thing there, is a trick used to succefully and smoothly move the animation, but it need to increase the width of the QWidget to being seen.
Not a good solution.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm completely new here, Tell me if the example is useless, I'll try to reproduce it as simple as a I can then (beside it uses a giant bunch of code)

Comment: I recommend using QgraphicsView, QgraphicsScene and its items to perform such tasks, in addition to reading about QAnimations. Qt is a powerful library and for every thing has something appropriate, do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I agree with @eyllanesc, Qt has some better classes to do what you want (I do not know enough about animation to point out which ones, `QGraphicsScene` seems a good start). As long as you move your QWidget it **needs to be repaint**, painting a widget is not about computing animation but really the moment you actually draw the pixels on your screen, it has to be executed every time at least one pixel is moved or changed in your QWidget (and Qt manages the *when* it has to be done).